# URLs "lastchecked" not printed in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibdesk

For my thesis I have to adhere to my university's standard (for thesis layouts).

With the following MWE I receive the desired result for printing URLs in the bibliography, but the field for `lastchecked` isn't printed:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@url{Google,
    author = {{Google Ireland Limited}},
    title = {Google},
    url = {https://google.de},
    urldate = {1997-09-15},
    lastchecked = {2023-04-16}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[url]{url}{<\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat[url]{urldate}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[url]{lastchecked}{\mkbibbrackets{Zugriff \printdate{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{url}{%URLs
    \usebibmacro{author}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\addnbspace}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{url}%
    \setunit{\addnbspace}
    \usebibmacro{urldate}%
    \setunit{\addnbspace}
    \printfield{lastchecked}% is not printed 
}

\begin{document}
    \cite{Google}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As literature management program I am using BibDesk which gives me the two different dates `urldate` (the release date of of the URL/content) as well as `lastchecked` (the last time I visited the URL) which I both need due to the aforementioned standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default entry types and field types in [BibDesk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibDesk) are for [BibTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX), and are different from those for BibLaTeX. (See [BibLaTeX cheat sheet](http://tug.ctan.org/info/biblatex-cheatsheet/biblatex-cheatsheet.pdf), but ignore that it says "BibTeX database file" in some places; it should say "BibLaTeX database file" instead.)

The `lastchecked` field is for BibTeX. The equivalent in BibLaTeX is `urldate`. The release date of the URL/content should go in `date`.

See [BibLaTeX Types and Fields](https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/wiki/Tips_and_Tricks/#biblatex-types-and-fields) on the BibDesk wiki for information about how to configure BibDesk's entry types and field types for BibLaTeX.

(However, keep in mind that [Biber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biber_(LaTeX)) can understand most BibTeX field types, so if you have already built your bibliographic database using BibTeX field types, you may want to keep most of BibDesk's default configuration and make only a few changes to the incompatible fields that are causing your problem.)